# Spring boot - How to select one datasource from multiple datasources after user selects one from UI?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My requirement - 
User selects one value from dropdown & depending on that value I should be able to select one datasource.
I configured 2 datasources like this.

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

& then defining it's properties in application.properties file.
But how to get one datasource value out of these 2 at runtime after uesr selection?

Comment: Are you accessing the `DataSource` directly in your code or are you expecting some library to do that for you. The reason I am asking is that you added the `spring-data-jpa` label on your issue. If not, just inject the `ApplicationContext` and get a bean by name (`context.getBean(theBeanName, DataSource.class)`

Comment: I am accessing it through spring data jpa so I don't have to get it explicitly from application context

Comment: Let me try getting it from application context like you mentioned

Comment: I am getting both datasource beans but how should I set that bean to datasource to use it further?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases